# Error on Left Join three tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I set all the day reading Questions on stackoverflow of how to jouin 3 table in one SQL query , I try it many times but it did not work !!

my case are like this , I want to understand how it is work and how should I do it.

my SQL query is the following :

```
SELECT students.id,
       students.name,
       students.age,
       students.subjects,
       students.teacher from students
LEFT JOIN subjects ON students.subjects = subjects.subject_id
LEFT JOIN teachers ON students.teacher = teachers.teacher_id
```

What is the wrong in my case ?

Comment: you have a typo in there - it should be `from` not `form`. Also it would help if you could show your table schema

Comment: form must be from. Error in spelling of from.

Comment: Sorry but the problem remains

Comment: What about `LEFT JOIN teachers ON student.teacher = teachers.teacher_id_column_name`  ?

Comment: Is your table `student` or `students` ?
`SELECT students.id,  students.name,   students.age,    students.subjects, students.teacher from students...`

Comment: Another typo: `student` should be `students`. Also, in your second `JOIN`, it should be something like this: `students.teacher` = `teachers`.`teacher_id`.

Comment: How is the data stored in `students.subjects`? Is it just a single id, like `subjects.subject_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a condition in the second `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.age, s.subjects, s.teacher 
FROM students s LEFT JOIN
     subjects su
     ON s.subjects = su.subject_id LEFT JOIN
     teachers t
     ON s.teacher = t.teacher;
```

You should note, though, that the query is only fetching columns from `students`, so you don't need the joins (at this point, I'm guessing the query you want is more complicated).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but putting `LEFT JOIN` on the same line as `FROM` or `ON` looks totally weird... anyway, correct answer.

Comment: where did the the "s" in students s  came from ?

Comment: It's an alias. You can say `FROM students AS s` and, with that, refer to it with just `s`. Makes it shorter and a little clearer. The `AS` - as it's the case here - is optional.

Answer (score -1):

Try this bro

```
select stud.id,stud.name,stud.age,stud.subjects,stud.teacher
from  students stud, subjects sub ,teachers tea 
where stud.subjects = sub.subject_id and stud.teacher = tea.teacher_id
```

Comment: This works differently: a `LEFT JOIN` also selects students that do not have a teacher.

Comment: (Side note / pet peeve: why do you abbreviate the table names when it does not significantly reduce the length? It only makes it harder to understand).

Comment: @Daan Wilmer why you downvote my suggestion..Anything wrong in that

Comment: You all guys having too much of reputations.so that you won't bother about new learners

Comment: The answer is not clear, how ever I am not the one who downvot your answer, thanks any way

Comment: @Evemtor Thank you..iam just suggesting ..thats all

Comment: @Goutham I downvoted because it is a wrong answer, in that the behaviour is slightly different from the desired behaviour: the desired behaviour seems to be that of a `LEFT JOIN`, you're describing an (implicit) `INNER JOIN`. See here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins#38578
Furthermore, you don't explain _why_ this should work. If you give an explanation, people can understand what went wrong, and improve their own coding. I'd be happy to remove the downvote if the answer were correct, and upvote for a good explanation.

Comment: @DaanWilmer yes you are right.Thank you for your valuable suggestion and a deep tutorial about JOINS.